# Error when changing IE automation code to XML

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, xml-parsing

I recently started working with XML automation and after changing some basic IE automation code over, I seem to be getting an error. Here's the HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="group-2 first">
    <td class="date-col">
        <a href="/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48606/teamone-vs-merciless">
            <div class="time" data-time-format="d/M/yy" data-unix="1498593600000">27/6/17</div>
        </a>
    </td>
    ......SOME MORE HTML HERE......
    </tr>
......SOME MORE HTML HERE......
</tbody>
```

And here's the code i'm using in Excel VBA:

```
Sub readData()

Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://www.hltv.org/stats/matches", False
XMLPage.send

If XMLPage.Status <> 200 Then MsgBox XMLPage.statusText
html.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText


For Each profile In html.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).Children
    Debug.Print profile.getElementsByClassName("date-col")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).getAttribute("href") 'Run time error '438' here
Next

End Sub
```

I'm getting the Run time error '438' at the debug print code. seems to be happening when getting the class but i'm unsure why. It works fine if I use this for example:

```
Debug.Print profile.innertext
```

Comment: Typically, when working with an XML request, you'd avoid using an `HTMLDocument`, and instead use an `MSXML2.DOMDocument`, which has more powerful querying capabilities, but your HTML must be valid XHTML first.

Comment: can you split Debug.Print profile.getElementsByClassName("date-col")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).getAttribute("href") into multiple lines to see which line is the offending code.

Comment: Thanks for looking, i tried this and found it's happening when searching for 'getElementsByClassName("date-col")(0)'. If I use innertext as shown at the bottom of my question - it works fine. Any ideas please?

Comment: What type is `profile` declared as? `getElementsByClassName` comes from `IHTMLElement6` in this context whereas `getElementsByTagName` comes from `IHTMLElement2`

Comment: Interesting to see. I hadn't declared it and the code above is all there was - is there a declaration that would work for both element types?

Comment: Just adding `Dim profile As IHTMLElement6` could work - put this with the other declarations at the top of your `Sub`. Also, put `Option Explicit` as the first line of the module to require variables to be declared

Comment: Thank you barrowc - adding that one declaration made everything run perfectly!

Comment: Any recommendations on what deceleration to use for 'html' (currently set to `MSHTML.HTMLDocument`) to get the same effect for something like this please? `html.getElementsByClassName("team-left")(0).getElementsByTagName("div")(0).innertext`

Comment: If you're looking at the same page as before then I don't see any elements with a class of "team-left" in the source for that page.

Comment: This one's for a different page, but as it does not use any loops within it which I can declare a variable as `HTMLElement6`as done for the previous code - I am using the html variable directly to access both `classname` and `tagname` (as shown in last comment). Confusion is, how do I set something which is already declared as 'MSHTML.HTMLDocument' to `HTMLElement6` or find a way to split this code up so that I can run it through a separate variable which is declared as `HTMLElement6` so that I get no errors? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`profile` refers to a row, and `profile.cells(0)` will refer to the first column in that row.  So try...

```
profile.cells(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).getAttribute("href")
```

Also, `profile` should be declared as `HTMLTableRow`.

Comment: That line of code seems to return the desired href.  So why the down vote?

Comment: I'm not sure who down voted but it works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Worked for me:

```
Sub readData()

    Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument, links, a, i

    XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://www.hltv.org/stats/matches", False
    XMLPage.send

    If XMLPage.Status <> 200 Then MsgBox XMLPage.statusText
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

    Set links = html.querySelectorAll("td.date-col > a")
    Debug.Print links.Length

    For i = 0 To links.Length - 1
        Debug.Print links(i).href
    Next

    Set links = Nothing
    Set html = Nothing

End Sub
```

FYI when I used `For Each` to loop over the `links` collection Excel would reliably crash, so I'd stay with the loop shown

Comment: I was able to use `For Each` with an MSXML `IXMLDOMSelection` ;-P

Answer (score 2):

The URL you are using isn't serving valid XML, but it's recoverable with some simple regex replacements. Once we have some valid XML, we can load that into a DOM document and use XPath to select the nodes as required:

```
Option Explicit

'Add references to:
' - MSXML v3
' - Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

Sub test()

  Const START_MARKER As String = "<table class=""stats-table matches-table"">"
  Const END_MARKER As String = "</table>"

  With New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    .Open "GET", "https://www.hltv.org/stats/matches", False
    .send
    If .Status = 200 Then

      'The HTML isn't valid XHTML, so we can't just use the http.XMLResponse DOMDocument
      'Let's extract the HTML table

      Dim tableStart As Long
      tableStart = InStr(.responseText, START_MARKER)

      Dim tableEnd As Long
      tableEnd = InStr(tableStart, .responseText, END_MARKER)

      Dim tableHTML As String
      tableHTML = Mid$(.responseText, tableStart, tableEnd - tableStart + Len(END_MARKER))

      'The HTML table has invalid img tags (let's add a closing tag with some regex)
      With New RegExp
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(\<img [\W\w]*?)"">"
        Dim tableXML As String
        tableXML = .Replace(tableHTML, "$1"" />")
      End With

      'And load an XML document from the cleaned up HTML fragment
      Dim doc As MSXML2.DOMDocument
      Set doc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
      doc.LoadXML tableXML

    End If
  End With

  If Not doc Is Nothing Then

    'Use XPath to select the nodes we need
    Dim nodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMSelection
    Set nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//td[@class='date-col']/a/@href")

   'Enumerate the URLs
    Dim node As IXMLDOMAttribute
    For Each node In nodes
      Debug.Print node.nodeTypedValue
    Next node

  End If

End Sub
```

Output:

```
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48606/teamone-vs-merciless
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48607/merciless-vs-teamone
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48608/merciless-vs-teamone
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48600/wysix-vs-fnatic-academy
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48602/skitlite-vs-nexus
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48604/extatus-vs-forcebuy
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48605/extatus-vs-forcebuy
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48599/planetkey-vs-gatekeepers
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48603/gatekeepers-vs-planetkey
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48595/wysix-vs-gambit
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48596/kinguin-vs-playing-ducks
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48597/spirit-academy-vs-tgfirestorm
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48601/spirit-academy-vs-tgfirestorm
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48593/fnatic-academy-vs-gambit
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48594/alternate-attax-vs-nexus
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48590/pro100-vs-playing-ducks
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48583/extatus-vs-ex-fury
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48589/extatus-vs-ex-fury
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48584/onlinerol-vs-forcebuy
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48591/forcebuy-vs-onlinerol
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48581/epg-vs-veni-vidi-vici
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48588/epg-vs-veni-vidi-vici
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48592/veni-vidi-vici-vs-epg
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48582/log-vs-gatekeepers
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48586/gatekeepers-vs-log
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48580/spraynpray-vs-epg
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48579/quantum-bellator-fire-vs-spraynpray
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48571/noxide-vs-masterminds
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48572/athletico-vs-legacy
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48578/node-vs-avant
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48573/funky-monkeys-vs-grayhound
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48574/grayhound-vs-funky-monkeys
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48575/hegemonyperson-vs-eclipseo
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48577/eclipseo-vs-hegemonyperson
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48566/masterminds-vs-tainted-black
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48562/grayhound-vs-legacy
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48563/noxide-vs-riotous-raccoons
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48564/avant-vs-dark-sided
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48565/avant-vs-dark-sided
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48567/eclipseo-vs-uya
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48568/uya-vs-eclipseo
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48560/uya-vs-new4
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48561/new4-vs-uya
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48559/jaguar-sa-vs-miami-flamingos
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48558/spartak-vs-binary-dragons
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48557/kungar-vs-spartak
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48556/igamecom-vs-fragsters
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48554/nordic-warthogs-vs-aligon
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48555/binary-dragons-vs-kungar
/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48550/havu-vs-rogue-academy
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the MSHTML.HTMLDocument reference there is no method getElementsByClassName.

You will need to loop through each row in the tbody you are selecting and then get the first td in that row and then get the first link in that td and read the href attribute from it. You could alternately compare the class attribute of the td but since it is the first element in the row there is no need to do that.